# ERROR001409 failed to write the output location

Tags: arcgis-pro

When I try to execute "Summarize Within" tool, it gives me the "`001409`" error (`"Failed to write the output location"`).

[image]

What is the reason of this error and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Does `c:\rda_model\scratch.gdb` actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and was completely puzzled.  I went back and looked at various different aspects including the basics of ensuring my parameters were set up correctly and had the right path names, etc.

I found that my pathnames were ultimately too long.  I changed the naming convention of my files and it worked just fine.

This error code is not in Esri's library of error codes.  I'll submit a ticket and see if I get a response as to why and try to remember to update here unless others have any other inputs!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  How long were your "too long" pathnames?  The paths in the question don't appear to be particularly long, but it's impossible to tell without knowing how long your paths were.